# How to locate the triggering function

Tags: kdb

I want to find the function that invokes all the other functions inside of my tick setup. Theortically I know .u.end calls the end of day function within the processes (rdb.q) for example, but I can't work out how I could backtrace this myself without prior knowledge. Additionally, how would i figure out when the .u.end function is triggered. Do i first check timers or is it a understanding of how each process or script runs?

Answer (score 1):

To truly know everything that is triggering functions in your process you'd have to harness all of the built-in callback functions (aka .z functions) to register all connections (.z.po), disconnections (.z.pc), sync calls (.z.pg) and async calls (.z.ps). From that you can trace all IPC communication. There's a page about it all here and a bunch of sample scripts: https://code.kx.com/q/kb/using-dotz/

Note that those examples were written some time ago but they should still hold up

Comment: Thanks! Is that possible within a system setup such as tick?

Comment: No, for a tick system you would likely have to turn off async message tracking because you would have so many async messages flowing through a tick system. It'd blow up your memory usage and slow the system down. Unless you knew for certain that certain async messages are coming from a feedhandler (you could tell from the handle once you've registered the connection) - then you could choose to not log/track asyncs from the feedhandlers but track them for any other connection. Either way you'd have to be pretty careful

Comment: Thanks for the help!